# SQL Server daily report multiple columns to rows

Tags: sql-server, pivot, unpivot

I have a table like:

```
create table t_daily_total(
                Id          bigint identity not null,
                ReportDay   date null,
                Value1      decimal(10,2)  default 0 null,
                Value2      decimal(10,2) default 0 null
            ...
                Valuen      decimal(10,2) default 0 null
            )
```

and I want to see it in a format like:

```
ValueName, [2021-01-01],[2021-01-02], .... [2021-05-05]
Value1,    1, 2, 3.....
Value2, 5, 6, 7...
....
Valuen, 8, 9 10...
```

Basically see the values by day. I am using SQL Server 2014. I checked into the pivot and unpivot, but still could not make it work. please help. Thanks!

Comment: Please update your question with your attempt at PIVOT. Also include some sample data.

Comment: Seems like you should be fixing your design. Don't have many `Value` columns, have 2 columns (something like `Value` and `ValueNumber`) and then 1 row per value. Normalising your data will make your queries so much easier.

Comment: the data looks like:
```
insert into t_daily_total(ReportDay, Value1, Value2, Value3.... Valuen) values
('2021-01-01',1, 2, 3...n),
('2021-01-02',1, 2, 3...n).
```
it might be easy to understand if change the column name from value1...valuen to field1, field2, fieldn, Make sense?

Comment: @lptr this is exactly what I need. it worked perfect, thank you so much!!

Answer (score 0):

I got it work like this:

```
[![--- table structure
create table t_daily_grand_total(
    Id          bigint identity not null,
    ReportDay   date null,
    ValueName   varchar(10) null,
    Value       decimal(10,2) default 0 null
    primary key(Id)
)

-- init data
declare @i int = 0
declare @d date = '2021-01-01'
while @i < 50
begin
    insert into t_daily_grand_total(ReportDay, ValueName, Value)  values
        (@d, 'v1',floor(rand()*60) + 20),
        (@d, 'v2',floor(rand()*60) + 20),
        (@d, 'v3',floor(rand()*60) + 20)
    set @i = @i + 1
    set @d = dateadd(day,1 , @d)
end

-- source data
select * from t_daily_grand_total

-- the final result
select * from
(select ReportDay, ValueName, Value from t_daily_grand_total) as st
pivot(
        sum(Value)
        for ReportDay in(\[2021-01-01\],\[2021-01-02\], \[2021-01-04\], \[2021-01-07\])
    ) as pt][1]][1]
```

Comment: now just need to make the columns dynamic, that is easy